# Visual studio code suppress pep8 warnings

Tags: visual-studio-code, pep8

How can I suppress pep8 warnings, in Visual studio code? What I want to do is to suppress E501 warning I don't want to get warnings where my code length is more than 80 chars. I'm using [Don Jayamanne's Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python) and here is my config file for vscode

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/workspace/virtualenvs/abr/bin/python3",
    "python.linting.enabled": true
}
```

I know that there is one another option **"python.linting.pep8Args": []** but I couldn't to get it work. I've installed pep8 on virtualenv

What I've already tried.

1. "python.linting.pep8Args": ['--ignore=E501']
2. "Searched all visual studio code settings"

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Either use setup.cfg for single project or change your user settings for all py files.

```js
{
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleArgs": [
        "--ignore=E501" 
    ]
}
```

Before [October 2019](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2019100-8-october-2019) all `pycodestyle` settings  were named `pep8`:

```js
{
    "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pep8Args": [
        "--ignore=E501" 
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do I do multiple ignores? I tried a second `--ignore` line and I tried "E501,E266" but neither works

Comment: @ElDude I'm probably too late, but this should work: `"python.linting.pep8Args": ["--ignore=E501", "--ignore=E301"]`

Comment: Also (for anyone ending up here) `--ignore=E301,E501,E266` works as well.

Comment: Is it possible to ignore a warning for just one function? pylint allows it putting comments like `# pylint: disable=no-self-argument`. Is there something similar if I want to ignore `D403` for just one docstring of a function?

Answer (score 30):

If you want to change the line length, add this in your User Settings file

```
{ 
  "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
  "python.linting.pep8Args": ["--max-line-length=120" ]
}
```

previous code was giving me `'EOF'` error, so i edited it

Answer (score 17):

I was fighting with this a couple of weeks ago.  What I ended up doing was adding a `setup.cfg` file into the root folder of my project and putting the following in it:

```
[pep8]
ignore = E501
```

Comment: It worked for me, but is there any workarounds to make it for all projects at a time instead of creating setup.cfg for every projects?

Comment: The [documentation for pep8](http://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.7.x/intro.html#configuration) indicates that it is possible to create a user-level configuration file, but I have to admit that I haven't tried this.

Comment: This works for me:
```"python.linting.pep8Args": [
        "--ignore=E501"
    ],```

Answer (score 8):

this worked for me:

```
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.linting.flake8Args": ["--ignore=E501"]
```

Answer (score 5):

To ignore multiple pycodestyle warnings:

```
{
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleArgs": [
        "--ignore=E501,W503" 
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try double quote `"` instead of single `'`

`['--ignore=E501']` --> `["--ignore=E501"]`

It worked for me. Don't forget to restart the program.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting for vscode 1.31.1

solved it via modify settings.json

```js
{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Ocean",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Args": ["--ignore=E501", "--verbose"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not using flake8Args but Pylama (for example) the configuration change on settings.json is similar as described before:
`"python.linting.pylamaArgs": ["--max_line_length=120"]`
or
`"python.linting.pylamaArgs": [""--ignore=E501" "]`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was adding the code snippet below to my user settings.json file. This was mentioned above but without the settings.json.

```
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.linting.flake8Args": ["--ignore=E501"]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct. However you have to start the VScode to see the difference.  (I would prefer vs auto update itself.)