# VS Code PEP8 error types

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pep8

Was successfull to enable VS Code with PEP8 based on 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_pep8

However,now I need to specify a list of PEP8 errors to ignore. How would I do that?

Comment: You set those options in your [project config](http://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#configuration) and VS Code should read it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual studio code suppress pep8 warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831593/visual-studio-code-suppress-pep8-warnings)